# How to make spring security allow using rest services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have spring web application with spring security and I use rest services to access data. I have two questions about this.

First, I can't make spring security to allow me to send POST http request and add something to database. I tried to permit this request but spring security still denies access.

```
 http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/services/rest/registerUser").permitAll();
```

Second question, what is the best practice with securing rest services? I definitely don't want to let someone send data to database through rest services. So what is the best way to allow using services from inside of my app and restrict every other rest request?

Comment: You need to enable anonymous access for the `permitAll` to work. Without it you won't have an authentication object and access still fails. You could ignore everything but that way you also loose the security headers which get set on a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the overloaded `configure(WebSecurity web)` method in `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with the following implementation;

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/services/rest/registerUser");
}
```

Furthermore if you allow access to your REST Api from a Host other than the Host where your REST Api is placed, then you need to use Cors Headers.

> what is the best practice with securing rest services? I definitely
>   don't want to let someone send data to database through rest services.
>   So what is the best way to allow using services from inside of my app
>   and restrict every other rest request?

Most widely used and secure way of protecting REST Apis is by using OAuth2. You can use Spring Security OAuth2 project to achieve this.

Another way is to use JWT Tokens, which also can be achieved using Spring Security and a bit of code.

Comment: Thank you for the information. And I am just curious, Ignoring web request did work, but do you have any idea why my code with`permitAll()` didn't allow me to post that request?